# Gzip files are not being read by the Nginx server, even though gzip compression is enabled

Tags: angular, nginx, gzip

When analyzing my site on PageSpeed Insights it suggests to enable text compression, however the files that it mentions have already been gzipped, and gzip compression is already enabled on my nginx server.

The files PageSpeed Insights said needed to be gzipped in my Angular dist package are: `main.js`, `polyfills.js`, `styles.css`

All of those files have been successfully gzipped via `ng build --prod && gzip-all "dist/*.*"`, so they exist in the dist folder.

[image]

**Network Tab** shows gzip content encoding is enabled on the nginx server:

[image: **Network Tab** shows gzip content encoding is enabled]

**Nginx.config** Gzip Settings:

```
    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
```

For some reason it's not reading the gzipped files.

Comment: Check your logs and/or run a packet sniffer when you run PageSpeed to see what's going on.  I'm guessing PageSpeed is looking to use deflate, but you're only offering gzip.  This isn't a real problem.

Comment: PageSpeed says it checks for gzip, deflate or brotli

Comment: the gzip would work on the fly for the file types specified.  I'm not sure the pre-zipping them would actually work.  It seems there is a case but it is not standard and with specific content. https://serverfault.com/questions/144745/why-cant-i-pre-zip-server-files/144752#144752

Comment: @jcuypers will the nginx server automatically gzip the files? Angular no longer gzips on prod builds, so I figured it would have to be done manually.

Comment: well, yes, if you activate the correct mime-types.  please check my aswer + refer to the docs. in the link.  I think nginx with gzip on the fly css / js / json / ,,, will be more than ok and do-able.  plus maybe http/2  and you are good to go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default it only compresses text/html.  you need to uncomment other mime types you want to compress like:

```
gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
```

https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/compression/

Comment: Oh wow I didn't realize ```#``` was for commenting things out -.- such a simple solution, I feel stupid. Thank you!

Comment: btw... below in the doc.  there is a secton about gzip_static.   this might work also for you with pre-zip.      `gzip_static on;`  but i don't think its worth the trouble since gzip doesnt take a lot of cpu